# performance measures of MongoDB and Hbase with Shared Storage

Tags: mongodb, hbase, nas, san

what are the performance measures of MongoDB and Hbase with Shared Storage (SAN and NAS)

is it better to use local disks as it is in Cassandra? or one can use shared storage with MONGO and HBASE, i have gone through some blogs, n the only answers i m able to get are

**Avoid Remote File Systems: Remote file storage can create performance problems in MongoDB** .

**MongoDB does not require shared storage (e.g., storage area networks). MongoDB can use local attached storage as well as solid state drives (SSDs)**

and for hbase **works best with JBOD**

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad to meaningfully answer. What are you trying to accomplish? Mongo by it's nature is a node distributed database. The point of it is you have multiple instances of mongo nodes with fully isolated storage.

You *can* SAN attach if you want. You don't have to. You *shouldn't* use NFS with mongo datastores - that'll give you all sorts of grief.

But as measuring performance - find what's important to you; measure that.